# position of brushes on the commutator in a dc generator

Tags: dc, generator

i am having a hard time understanding why do we place the brushes on the Magnetic neutral axis, the textbook simply says, because this is where the current reversal takes place, is the point where emf from different meet is the same as the point of current reversal?

Answer (score 1):

Current reversal means the current is 0.  It is desirable to commute here because 0 current means no arching.  The increases the life of the brushes and commutator segments.  This can be done by rotating the brush card or using compensation windings.

Comment: I read more about it, and i found out that we put the brushes where the current reverses because this is where the sum of the emf of the conductors In the parallel paths meet, but why does the flow of current cause arching?

Comment: The motor windings act as a big inductor so will resist any change in current, if you suddenly break contact than the voltage will increase to keep the current flowing to the point of forming an electric arc. If you make the switch when current is already  zero this is avoided.